# Combine Worksheet Events

Tags: excel, vba

I have challenged myself on this one but have failed so far. I have two Worksheet_Change events that are triggered on the same concept of the user adding data and receiving a pop up message if incorrect.

I have tried to combine them but keep getting errors.

Code 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim NumA As Variant, NumB As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Set the relevant range
    Set rngToCheck = Union(Range("G12:G42"), Range("J12:J42"))

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        For i = 12 To 42 Step 2 '<~~ Loop through only even rows
            NumA = Range("G" & i).Value
            NumB = Range("J" & i).Value

            If IsNumeric(NumA) And IsNumeric(NumB) And NumB <> 0 Then
                If ((NumB - NumA) / NumA) * 100 < 50 Then
                    MsgBox "The Glass U-value and Total System U-value appear very similar. Please check the input values for accuracy!"
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Code 2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(3))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Columns(3), Cell.Value) > 1 Then
                MsgBox "This Glazing Reference already exists. Please ensure you have a unique reference identifier less than 20 characters in length", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
            End If

        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

I would like both `Worksheet_Change` events to run without them crashing.

Comment: What difficulty are you facing.. Use `ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then` with the code that I gave an combine them?

Comment: @SiddharthRout `ElseIf` might fail if a range (not single cell) is changed that affects *both* ranges which need to be checked. This would happen if you copy/paste a entire row for example. Therefore I suggest to use a second `If` statment, so both are checked.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth...i updated the code with a WorksheetFunction. CountIf in Code 2 above. Is the instruction to separate the code with 'ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then', removing the End Sub in the first piece of code and Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)?

Comment: @Vietman78 see my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim NumA As Variant, NumB As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Set the relevant range
    Set rngToCheck = Union(Range("G12:G42"), Range("J12:J42"))

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        For i = 12 To 42 Step 2 '<~~ Loop through only even rows
            NumA = Range("G" & i).Value
            NumB = Range("J" & i).Value

            If IsNumeric(NumA) And IsNumeric(NumB) And NumB <> 0 Then
                If ((NumB - NumA) / NumA) * 100 < 50 Then
                    MsgBox "The Glass U-value and Total System U-value appear very similar. Please check the input values for accuracy!"
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(3))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Columns(3), Cell.Value) > 1 Then
                MsgBox "This Glazing Reference already exists. Please ensure you have a unique reference identifier less than 20 characters in length", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
            End If

        Next Cell
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Su
```

b

Answer (score -2):

What is the issue? Just put them together.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim NumA As Variant, NumB As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Set the relevant range
    Set rngToCheck = Union(Range("G12:G42"), Range("J12:J42"))

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        For i = 12 To 42 Step 2 '<~~ Loop through only even rows
            NumA = Range("G" & i).Value
            NumB = Range("J" & i).Value

            If IsNumeric(NumA) And IsNumeric(NumB) And NumB <> 0 Then
                If ((NumB - NumA) / NumA) * 100 < 50 Then
                    MsgBox "The Glass U-value and Total System U-value appear very similar. Please check the input values for accuracy!"
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If


    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(3))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Columns(3), Cell.Value) > 1 Then
                MsgBox "This Wall Reference already exists. Please ensure you have a unique reference identifier less than 20 characters in length", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
            End If

        Next Cell
    End If


Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you both for taking your time to assist me on this. I simply missed of and End If statement. Basic i know but at least i am learning from the process.

Comment: Be aware that this incorporates the error handling from the first Sub , that if triggered will bypass the second sub.  May or may not be what the OP requires

Comment: @chrisneilsen I guess the error handling is just incorporated to not leave `EnableEvents = False` in case of an error since I put the code 2 within `EnableEvents = False` it of course must also trigger the error handling. Otherwise he would need to put it outside the `EnableEvents = False`. • But anyway there is no reason to disable the events in this code since I see nothing that could cause another event in this code. Also he could skip error handling completely if  he checks for `NumA <> 0`.

Comment: @Vietman78 Make sure you also check for `NumA <> 0` since you devide by `NumA`!